# What is URL from Travis CI for Authorization Callback. Generating Github Token

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, travis-ci, github-pages

What should I put in the indicated space in the img?

I'm trying to generate a github token to connect to TravisCI but I do not know what the URL is.

In the case of Netlify he also made me generate a token but he gave me this URL: https://api.netlify.com/auth/done.

The problem is I can not find the TravisCI URL.

[image: Screenshot Github token]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instead use a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/), as detailed in "[TravisCI GitHub Deployment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pages/#setting-the-github-token)"

> You’ll need to generate a personal access token with the public_repo or repo scope (repo is required for private repositories).
>   Since the token should be private, you’ll want to pass it to Travis securely in your [repository settings](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings) or via [encrypted variables in `.travis.yml`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables#Defining-encrypted-variables-in-travisyml).

No URL needed in that case.
Especially considering [TravisCI use of GitHUb OAuth scope](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/github-oauth-scopes/#legacy-webhooks):

> Before GitHub Apps, we used scoped OAuth tokens to integrate with GitHub.
>   As of May 2018, OAuth-based integration is considered our “Legacy” integration.